# Extract n-character substring while ignoring spaces

Tags: php, regex

I need to extract a substring (for instance 22 characters) but I need to ignore spaces when counting the number of characters. For example:

```
$para = "While still in high school I signed up to participate in amateur night at the Educational Alliance. I wanted to show my mother I had talent.";
```

Let's say I need to get the substring that contains the 22 first characters but without counting the spaces. `substr` doesn't work:

```
echo substr($para, 0, 22); // => While still in high sc
```

But I need to get

```
// => While still in high school
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Are you trying to get whole words?

Comment: @JayBlanchard no, not specially, if I need to get the whole word I know that I can search for the last white space in my substring.

Comment: Then your question is not quite clear. If you ignore spaces you will get `While still in high scho` without getting the whole word at the end as you have asked for. You show `22` in your code, but use `20` as your for "for instance".

Answer (score 1):

```
^(?=((?>.*?\S){20}))
```

Try this.Grab the capture or group.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/fM9lY3/42

This uses `lookahead` to capture `20` groups of `any character and a non space character`. Precisely,lookahead will search for groups ending with `non space` character.Because it is non greedy,it will search first such `20` groups.

Comment: The answer is better now, but the *solution* is still bad.  If there are fewer than 20 non-whitespace characters, your regex crashes before it can fail ([DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/fM9lY3/41)).  Of course, you probably should be using `{1,20}` instead of `{20}` so it *doesn't* fail, but the source of the problem is using `.*?` to "skip" the whitespace characters; what have you got against `\s*`?   Also, the lookahead is unnecessary, and with it gone you don't need the capturing group, either.

Comment: Putting `.*?\S` in an atomic group plugs the leak, but if you use `\s*` instead of `.*?`, there's no leak to plug.  If `\s*` runs out of whitespace characters to match, and `\S` can't match the next one, the match fails immediately.  As for the lookahead, its only effect is that the regex doesn't consume what it matches, forcing you to compensate with a capturing group.

Comment: may I know how to combine it the syntax in to the code?

Comment: Yes, I have check it. But I only see 1 line of  your syntax. I confused how to combine it to the code

Comment: php language please

Comment: @AgnesPalit https://regex101.com/r/fM9lY3/42/codegen?language=php ?

Comment: @Amaynut did any answer work for you? if yes can u accept and close this question? if not , can you add the one you used and accept it?

Comment: may I know how to modify the regex if I would like start from word number 5 instead of 0?

Answer (score 0):

First, use `str_replace()` to create a string $parawithoutspaces that consists of $para, without the spaces, like so:

```
$parawithoutspaces=str_replace(" ", "", $para);
```

Then, use substr() get the first 20 characters of $parawithoutspaces like so:

```
print substr($parawithoutspaces, 0, 20);
```

Or, combining the two steps into one and eliminating the need for the intermediate variable $parawithoutspaces:

```
print substr(str_replace(" ", "", $para),0,20);
```

Comment: `echo substr(str_replace(" ", "", $para),0,20);` And it is `substr` with a `t`

Comment: This solution doesn't work because I will it returns a substring without spaces, which is not what I want. What I want is to get a sub string with spaces but the spaces are not counted in the length.

Comment: actualy it does not show the result with the space. I think she ask you how to show the result by ignore the space, but still show the space in the end

Answer (score 0):

you just need to provide a `string` and length you want to be extracted from that `string` and function will return that string of specified length(yes return string will have spaces in it, but spaces won't be included in string).

Here is snippet.

```
$para = "While still in high school I signed up to participate in amateur night at the Educational Alliance. I wanted to show my mother I had talent.";
function getString($str, $length){
    $newStr = "";
    $counter = 0;
    $r = array();
    for($i=0; $i<strlen($str); $i++) 
         $r[$i] = $str[$i];

    foreach($r as $char){
        $newStr .= $char;
        if($char != " "){
            $counter += 1;  
        }

        //return string if length reached.
        if($counter == $length){
            return $newStr;
        }
    }
    return $newStr;
}

echo getString($para, 20);
//output: While still in high scho

echo getString($para, 22);
//output: While still in high school
```

Comment: This solution will work, I already though about that, but if I need a substring of 1000 characters, but I will need to fire my loop 1000 times.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, it is my code, $result is final string you want :

```
$arr1 = substr( $string,0,20);
$arr1 = explode(" ",$arr1);
array_pop($arr1);
$result = implode(" ",$arr1);
```