# Regex get first n characters ignoring space

Tags: php, regex

I have found a solution on how to cut a text by using regex.

```
^(?=((?:.*?\S){40})) // GET FIRST 40 CHARACTERS (IGNORING SPACES)
```

Fron: [Extract n-character substring while ignoring spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31792387/php-get-a-substring-ignoring-spaces)

The problem is if I entered this: `asdgfhtjshhhhhhhhhasdasdasdass asd`, nothing has been extracted.

Here is the regex101 link: https://regex101.com/r/fM9lY3/5#javascript

Comment: Judging by the title, I think you just need `^(?:\s*\S){40}`.

Comment: @stribizhev It seems that OP don't wants to match spaces!

Comment: Then the question is unclear. MBC.

Comment: That regex is awful.  I've added a comment to the answer you got it from explaining what's wrong with it, but  [hek2mgl's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34238156/20938) fixes all its problems.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the following regex:

```
^(\s*\S){1,40}
```

You don't need a lookahead assertion, you can simply put zero or more space characters and a non-space character into a capturing group. Then trailing quantifier will ensure it occurs up to 40 times. The key here is the optional space.

Try it: https://regex101.com/r/fM9lY3/40

Answer (score 0):

This is because {40} means **exactly** 40, and the text you inputted has less than 40 characters. Try with {1,40} (which means from 1 to 40):

```
^(?=((?:.*?\S){1,40}))
```

Answer (score 0):

This one makes just a small usage of regex, but it works

```
$x = "asdgfhtjshhhhhhhhhasdasdasdass asd";

$result = substr(implode("", preg_split('/\s+/', $x)), 0, 40);
```